# Data (BLOB) modifies after insertion to mySql (jsp, servlet)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, blob

**My Problem.** MySQL changes data I upload to db as a Blob file and then retrieve it back. So image does not want to appear on my jsp page.

My program uses jsp/servlet datasource connection to MySql.

```
dataSource = ConnectionUtil.getMySQLDataSource();
```

Connection works perfectly with all the other tables in my program.

**Step 1.**
My problem occurs when I am trying to upload image using jsp ...

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Image">
                File to upload: <input type="file" name="upfile"><br/>

                <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Press"> to upload the file!
</form>
```

**Step 2.**
... and sending it to the doPost method by passing request to InputStream. Then I just reading inputStream into byte[]. And translating **byte[]** into **java.sql.Blob** type.

```
for (Part part : request.getParts()) {
InputStream is = request.getPart(part.getName()).getInputStream();
int i = is.available();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (i > 0) {
                byte[] b = new byte[i + 1];
                is.read(b);
}
}
```

**Step 3.**
After all these steps I am sending the MySql connection to my java class Model. Then I am transforming my byte[] b file to Blob file.

```
Blob image = new SerialBlob(b);
```

**Step 4.**
And sending this data (and some more stuff) to the MySql database with PreparedStatement and storing it there as `MEDIUMBLOB`.

```
String strPsInsertPic = "INSERT INTO `pics`(picid,image, imagelength, name) " +
                    "VALUES ('" + (picid) + "','" + image + "','" + image_length + "','" + name + "')";
            psInsertPic = conn.prepareStatement(strPsInsertPic);
            psInsertPic.executeUpdate();
```

Furthermore, I am closing Connection and PreparedStatement.

**Step 5.**
On another jsp page I am going to the doGet method in my servlet (with setting the connection to DB of course) and making the statement there to take image as Blob. And converting it to the byte[].

```
    preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT image,imagelength,type FROM pics WHERE picid ='" + picid + "'");
    resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
bImage = rs.getBlob("image");
byte[] bdata = bImage.getBytes(1, (int) bImage.length());
```

So, when I am looping through the **byte[] b** after **Step 2** I am getting next data for my image:
*-1-40-1-32016747073700120010100-1-37067086676587779981012201312111112251819152029263130292628283236463932344435282840554 ... (lots of numbers there)*

And when I am doing the same at the end of **Step 5** after converting Blob from MySQL to byte[]. I am getting next data:
*10697118971204611511310846114111119115101116461151011141059710846831011141059710866108111986450531025054485653*

My Chrome Console in Inspect Element shows next error:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

*I am not posting here some stuff like try/catch blocks and setting the connection. Don't want to obstruct you with dozens lines of code. I have already checked that data does not change while translations byte[] to Blob and otherwise in java code. So the problem is that MySQL modifies data somehow.
Also want to mention that I am using the Tomcat server.*

Would be great if someone helped me to understand the problem and how to solve it. (I don't want to store data as huge varchar or byte[].) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `available` is not a good indicator of the file size.

try

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte b [] = new byte [1024];
int read = 0;
while ((read = is.read(b)) != -1) {
    // add b to baos
    baos.write(b);
}

Blob image = new SerialBlob(baos.toByteArray ());
```

Comment: Thank for the response. I am not sure I understand what is "read" variable?
Also, how do you use baos after line: baos.write(b)?

And I think that data will be still changed in the MySQL after uploading and retrieving it. 
If you could a little bit more explain my problem in that you just shown me and in my question as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated the answer for you.  The problem with `available` is that it is just the amount of bytes that are `available` now - more data will come., whereas `read` will read until the end of the file.